# Found this in my wheel

Tags: wheels, rust, renault, clio

[image]

Hi there

I was driving along when I noticed a sound in my rear wheel. I stopped and found this inside. I'm unsure if I've went over it or it's fell off my car. Can anyone identify it please?

I have Renault Clio Initiale 2007.

Cheers

Comment: At first glance, it looks like a [rotor's dust shield](https://www.google.com/search?q=rotor+dust+shield), but the picture is pretty unclear. Can you light it a bit better? Also, what do you mean by "inside" the wheel?

Comment: Hi Josh, cheers for the reply. I can't see n option to add a pic to a reply unfortunately. Looking at dust shields on google though I think you may be right. By inside the wheel, I mean it was rattling around inside the rim as if it fell off, landed on the inside and spun round while I drove. Will the car be ok to drive with it off?

Comment: I've brightened the picture if that helps any.

Comment: The dust shields protect the brake system from getting too much road debris accumulating in the brake system. So the car is safe to drive without them, but you should get it replaced at earliest convenience to help prevent damage (and more repairs) later on.

Comment: Cheers. Shouldn't be using it much after tomorrow so I'll get it fixed after the holidays. Appreciated guys.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, now change your comment to an answer so we can all vote it up!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that's a piece of your [brake rotor's dust shield](https://www.google.com/search?q=rotor+dust+shield).

As [techturtle said](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/14696/found-this-in-my-wheel?noredirect=1#comment17613_14696), its lack doesn't pose an immediate danger, but since it keeps debris out of the brakes, you should get it replaced at your earliest convenience to avoid undue wear.

I don't have any specific knowledge of your car, but if replacing it does not involve moving the caliper, it would be straightforward to do yourself, if you're so inclined.

Comment: Cheers. Just back from the garage who confirmed your answers but said not to worry about it :/